# Excel/Visual Basic Error type mismatch run-time error 2147352571

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I am receiving this error when trying to get the values for the "Site" combo-box. Below are images of the Excel sheet and the error message, as well as the portion of code where the error is occurring. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

[(Screenshot of code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLCCe.jpg)

Hardcode - errors on line `Site.AddItem rstSite.Fields("mfg_site")`

```
Private Sub Site_Enter()
    Dim stSQL As String
    Dim rstSite As ADODB.Recordset

    ' First remove any existing
    Site.Clear
    DoEvents
    ' Load Widget
    stSQL = "select distinct mfg_site from suserflds join sample on sample.sampno=suserflds.sampno" & _
        " where cast(coldate as date) between '" & DateValue(DateFrom) & "' and '" & DateValue(DateTo) & "'" & _
        " order by mfg_site "
    Set rstSite = con.Execute(stSQL)
    While Not rstSite.EOF
        Site.AddItem rstSite.Fields("mfg_site")
        rstSite.MoveNext
    Wend
    Set rstSite = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `rstSite.Fields("mfg_site")` at the time of error?

Comment: The value at the time of the error is NULL

Comment: sounds like the value (Null) is not allowed for "site". Does asking fpor the value work  - e.g. msgbox rstSite.Fields("mfg_site") ?  Can you put a NULL into that field manually?

Comment: Try this `If Not IsNull(rstSite.Fields("mfg_site")) Then  Site.AddItem rstSite.Fields("mfg_site")`

Comment: That resolved the issue, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> The value at the time of the error is NULL – CShep878 11 mins ago

You cannot add Null Values. See this example

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ComboBox1.AddItem Null
End Sub
```

[image]
To handle Null, use this

```
If Not IsNull(rstSite.Fields("mfg_site")) Then Site.AddItem rstSite.Fields("mfg_site")
```

Interesting read about [NULL](https://web.archive.org/web/20080514091853/http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5034252.html)

> It's easy to think of null and blank entries as the same thing, but they aren't equal. The term “null” simply means the data is missing or unknown. That's not the same as saying the data doesn't exist, although it may not. Often, null entries are an indication that the value will be forthcoming or that someone is still searching for the data. Eventually, you may find that the data isn’t valid for that particular record, but until that consensus is reached, the value should remain null.